# Unable to save password utilizing bcrypt-ruby and has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt-ruby

We are moving from Devise to a more streamlined authentication process. If I can solve the following problem, I think I can get the rest of the authentication process working.

If one of our clients looses a password, they can submit their user ID and we will send them an email with a new password. The password that is sent in the email is not being saved in our system.

Gemfile:

```
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
```

Database Schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "username", limit: 255, null: false
    t.string   "password_digest", limit: 255
    ...
  end
```

User model:

```
  has_secure_password
  ...
  attr_accessible ... :username, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation,...
  ...
  def set_password(len = 12)
    chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a + ("0".."9").to_a
    newpass = ""
    1.upto(len) { |i| newpass << chars[rand(chars.size-1)] }
    self.password = self.password_confirmation = newpass
  end
```

users_controller:

```
  def send_new_password
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

    pw = @user.set_password
    @user.save

    UserMailer.new_password(@user).deliver_now
    redirect_to sign_in_path
  end
  ...
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(... :username, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation,... )
  end
```

I get invalid hash on this line: 'self.password = newpass'. If I change it to 'self.password_digest = newpass' then all proceeds but checking in the rails console 'puts u.password_digest' produces '=> nil'.

RESULT: We changed approach. No longer sending passwords in emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you want, but sending passwords to the user is bad practice. Any one telling you otherwise is wrong.

The devise gem has a module dedicated to resetting passwords, which involves email a  link for users to recover & set their own password: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/Devise/Models/Recoverable